# Batch convert dgn files to shp files using ogr2ogr

Tags: ogr, dgn

We have hundreds of dgn files which have to be converted to shapefiles. I am trying to use these commands to batch convert all the dgn files in a folder.

```
for %%f in (*.dgn) do ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" ".\point\%~nf.shp" "%%f" -where "OGR_GEOMETRY = 'POINT'" -skipfailures
for %%f in (*.dgn) do ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" ".\linestring\%~nf.shp" "%%f" -where "OGR_GEOMETRY = 'LINESTRING'" -skipfailures
for %%f in (*.dgn) do ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" ".\polygon\%~nf.shp" "%%f" -where "OGR_GEOMETRY = 'POLYGON'" -skipfailures
```

But I am getting an error of

> "|f" is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
>   program or batch file

Could anyone tell me what the problem with this command is?

Update: The problem is with the bat file format. It has to be saved in ANSI & not in other format's. The code given by Zoltan in the answer works perfectly

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27205097/ansi-unicode-conflict-in-batch-file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you run it from a batch (.bat) file you have to use double percent marks for '~nf' too:

`for %%f in (*.dgn) do ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" ".\point\%%~nf.shp" "%%f" -where "OGR_GEOMETRY = 'POINT'" -skipfailures`

Comment: Still getting the same error. "'■f' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

Comment: Try this: `for %%f in (*.dgn) do echo "%%~nf.shp"`. It works for me. Did you test your ogr2ogr command?

Comment: Still the same. "'■f' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

Comment: You have to use double "%%" in a bat file, if you type in your command at the command prompt use single "%", e.g.  type in: `for %f in (*.dgn) do echo "%~nf.shp"`

Comment: It's working if i run it through command prompt (single "%"). But if i run the same using bat file (Double %%), again getting the same error.

Comment: OK. Got it. The problem is with the bat file. It should be saved in ANSI not in unicode. I've edited my question and updated. Have a look