# Batch convert dgn files to separate shapefiles in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, dgn

Actually, currently we are doing dgn -> shp file conversion using ogr2ogr. [Batch convert dgn files to shp files using ogr2ogr](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/173594/batch-convert-dgn-files-to-shp-files-using-ogr2ogr)

The problem is, at times the point layer is not getting read properly & few attributes are missing. But, if we convert the dgn using xxx.dgn -> Export -> To Shapefile (multiple) all the attributes of the features are getting retained and annotaion layer & point layer is getting saved separately.

But we are doing it file by file. Is it possible to run this as a batch using Arcpy ?

I've tried with the code given in this site https://geonet.esri.com/thread/56828

It work's perfectly. But the files are saved in a gdb. I want it to be saved as separate shapefiles.

```
import arcpy  
import glob  
import os  
gdb = "D:/Arc/new.gdb"  
arcpy.env.workspace = gdb  
arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management("D:/Arc", "new.gdb")  
reference_scale = "1500"  
for file in glob.glob(r"D:\Arc\*.dgn"): 
outDS = arcpy.ValidateTableName(os.path.splitext("d" + os.path.basename(file)) [0])  
arcpy.CADToGeodatabase_conversion(file, gdb, outDS, reference_scale)
```

Comment: Just about everything is possible through ArcPy. I recommend you make an attempt, and alter this question if you get stuck.

Comment: Convert to DWG and then covert cad files to feature class via "CAD to geodatabase" in batch mode

Comment: I've edited the question and added the code which i've tried.

Answer (score 2):

Using python/arcpy you may use os.walk to iterate through a directory where you have many .dgn files and use [Feature Class to Feature Class](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001200000020000000) method to export the point, polyline, polygon...etc layers to shapefiles.

Comment: I would like to convert the files to separate Shapefile rather than Feature_Class.

Comment: feature class to feature class method does that.